# How to calculate tidal bulge on a shallow, enclosed body of water?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, gravity, fluid-statics, tidal-effect

The moon causes a tidal bulge because there is a differential in the gravitational field on the near vs far side of the Earth and the ocean is fluid and can distort to seek the new equilibrium state as the moon moves.

But this depends on the waters on all sides of the Earth being connected, right? As the tidal bulge extends to the moon on the near side, that water is being drained away from elsewhere.

So suppose we have a lake of a given depth and radius which is enclosed and separated from the rest of the oceans. Given the position of the moon relative to the Earth, and the location of the lake, how would we calculate the tidal effect on the lake water?

Comment: The moon does not cause any "tidal bulge." The drawings that you have seen that show Earth's oceans "bulging" toward and away from the moon are a lie. They don't show you the shape of the water. What they show is the shape of the _force_ that acts on the water, but how the water responds to that changing force nover time is much more complicated. https://youtu.be/PSJRymZ5bJs

Comment: Partially related, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/805834/23615